# JQuery sortable (glich/jump) with overflown container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-sortable

The problem is when the list is overflow:scroll and you have many divs and when you scroll to the bottom and try and move one, theres a bit of a glitch and jump. Something with position:abolute? I think?

**Works fine on O/MS/FF but not Chrome**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/Y7uV5/9/

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    .....
</ul>

$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    forceHelperSize: true,
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    revert: true,
    revert: 150,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    axis: "y",
    tolerance: "intersect"
});

$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

---

**Edit:** I just noticed the same thing happens on the **official jquery-ui demo page** http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/sortable/default.html 
Make the window small and you will notice the bug once scrolled down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to prevent this glitch with those 2 lines of code:

```
var sortHeight = $("#sortable").innerHeight();
$("#sortable").css({"min-height" : sortHeight});
```